# How do you recompile python in virtual env with --enable-shared

Tags: python, virtualenv

Once I made my virtualenv, Python was already installed. How do I add the option `--enable-shared`? Do I delete it or start virtualenv over from fresh? If I do that, how do I add the Python option? I don't want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a virtual environment, the Python binaries will be copied, not compiled. Quoting from the [`venv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments),

> It also creates a bin (or Scripts on Windows) subdirectory containing a copy of the python binary (or binaries, in the case of Windows)

But `--enable-shared` is an option for the `./configure` script, which is used during compilation of the Python from source code.

So, you first have to compile Python from the source code, with `--enable-shared` option, and then create virtual environment with the compiled python binary.

If you are using unix based OS, then by default, the installation will happen in `/usr/local` directory, so that you will not mess up with the current Python installation.

Moreover, instead of `sudo make install`, use `sudo make altinstall`. This will install the Python with the `major.minor` version format.